# How to have some space left and right from a Bootstrap container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-5

I am looking to get some space left and right from a Boostrap container.

At the moment I am doing it by having a 'fluid' container/section and setting some margin on both sides. That way we have some space left and right.

The problem with doing that is that on larger screens it will look horrible and it gets stretched out.
[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a more consistent left and right spacing outside the `container` when on a normal screen:
[image]
So that the spacing outside the `container` is always like 10% and not being stretched out on larger screens.

Here's a Codepen with what I have so far:
https://codepen.io/monsmado/pen/ZEorope

'codewise' it is not the most optimal, because I quickly copied it from my React/Next.js project

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you could set a `max-width: 1400px;` (or whatever you want) and `margin: 0 auto` on the `.hero`. You would need to override the other `!important` rules that are getting applied there.

Comment: That might be a solution. I think I am more looking for a consistent space on the left and right on all screen sizes, except mobile of course. Having it, for instance, expand outside the container on the left- and righthand side by 10%, 5rem or 50px.